# DNS Registration Using Non Windows DHCP

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

We are searching for a solution for our VPN users.  We use a Fortinet SSLVPN.  The Fortinet appliance issues DHCP to our clients.  It is configured to have the clients use our internal Windows DNS servers.  The clients are domain joined.  Is it possible to have these clients register with our DNS server without running a Windows DHCP server?

I have tried ipconfig /registerdns with no luck.

Thank You,
Eric

Comment: Are the devices that are connecting over the VPN joined to *your* AD domain? If so, are you allowing secure dynamic updates to your internal DNS zone?

Comment: Yes the systems are joined to our domain.  We are allowing Dynamic updates - Secure Only for our internal zone.

Comment: can you test with a Windows DHCP server and confirm the options in the response are the same? This may explain why you have this behavoiur.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test with a Windows DHCP server for this subnet/group.  Our other subnets are working fine when being issued by a Windows server.